# Difference in selector and element

Tags: jquery

Is there a difference between the following code

```
     $("li")
```

and

```
    $("<li>")
```

Comment: @Linuxios there should be a difference.

Comment: @charlietfl: Just read your anser, nevermind.

Answer (score 1):

The first will look for all `LI` in the page, the second creates a new LI element that can then be added to the page

For reference look at `jQuery()` method docs. There are 2 main sections that cover both of these cases

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/

Answer (score 1):

The first one selects all li-elements in DOM, the second one creates a detached new li-element without adding it to the DOM.

Regards